# Issue with using the chr() method to add \x to characters in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, hex

I'm trying to send Hex data via sockets to remote hardware.  The method I am using works for some data but not others, here is an example:

```
packet_list = ["00","00","00","00","00","05","FF","70","00","00","00"]
packet_list = [(int(x,16)) for x in packet_list]
packet_list = [(chr(x)) for x in packet_list]
```

This outputs:

```
['\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x07', '\xff', 'r', '\x00', '\x00', '\x06', '\x00', '\x00']
```

This is SO close to what I want, but I don't want the 'r' character, instead it should be a "hexified" version of 70, which would be \x70.  I realize that chr() is just giving me the ASCII representation of the int 114, but what I REALLY want is to simply have a string with \x in front of my hex numbers.

Comment: Your `packet_list` first line is **one string**, not a list. Python string representations show bytes in the ASCII printable range as ASCII characters, but they are still *the same byte*.

Comment: Matijin you are right, I am using a list but just mistyped it.  Will correct.

Comment: Your output doesn't match; `05` became `\x07`, `70` (ASCII P) became `r` (hex 72).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your first line of code gives you **one** string element:

```
>>> ["00"+"00"+"00"+"00"+"00"+"05"+"FF"+"70"+"00"+"00"+"00"]
['000000000005FF70000000']
```

The easiest method to turn a string with hex characters into bytes is to use [`binascii.unhexlify`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify):

```
>>> from binascii import unhexlify
>>> unhexlify('000000000005FF70000000')
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\xffp\x00\x00\x00'
```

or, using a list:

```
>>> unhexlify(''.join(["00","00","00","00","00","05","FF","70","00","00","00"]))
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\xffp\x00\x00\x00'
```

This is *one* set of bytes, not a list, but turning that into a list is as simple as calling `list()` on  that if you insist:

```
>>> list(unhexlify('000000000005FF70000000'))
['\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x05', '\xff', 'p', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00']
```

Note that the `p` there is just Python representing that byte as a ASCII printable character; it is still just the same byte:

```
>>> hex(ord('p'))
'0x70'
>>> chr(0x70)
'p'
>>> '\x70'
'p'
```

This is nothing to worry about, it's just a byte representation.

Comment: The problem is my hardware wants to see \x70 and throws up if it sees anything else.  Also, the 70 is actually a user-inputted command so I can't hard-code it into the packet.  I end up taking some user input, creating a list with the necessary bytes, and then turing it all into hex, then send it.  It works if the \x is included but doesn't work if I just send 0x0 bytes.  I can add the \x with the chr() command but it blows up on 70 by sending 'p' and my hardware pukes.

Comment: I will give this stuff a shot.  I've tried this method before and the hardware crashes.  I MUST send the hex as \x70 or it doesn't work.  This is a good start I guess, I'll work on it from here.

Comment: But that's not a Python problem; you are still sending a hex `70` byte; the fact that Python *displays* it as `'p'` has nothing to with this.

Answer (score -1):

First of all replace all the + with commas. You are just making a list with one big string element.

```
packet_list = ["00","00","00","00","00","05","FF","70","00","00","00"]
packet_list = [hex(int(x, 16)) for x in packet_list]
print packet_list
```

output:

['0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x5', '0xff', '0x70', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0']

Comment: This is perfect but when I send this to sockets my hardware pukes.  I think I need the \x escape between each hex number.  Do you know a way to add it?  Formerly I was using the chr() method which added the \x but also misinterpreted some of the characters.

Comment: These are literal hex strings. You may as well prepend the original strings with `0x` and be done with it. There is no other difference.

Comment: Your code goes from hex string -> int -> hex string, but with `0x` in front and lowercased.

Comment: ahh I see the problem. There is no problem. I thought the OP just wanted to print them out and see them that way 0xFF, etc ... The explanation that @MartijnPieters gave is all you need. If you want to print them to screen to see them in hex format do what I said, but do not try to send that to your remote hardware.

Answer (score -1):

I'll bite - why not just leave the strings as strings instead of converting to integer and back?

EG:
packet_list = ["00","00","00","00","00","05","FF","70","00","00","00"]
print(list('\x{}'.format(byte_) for byte_ in packet_list))

Comment: Not familiar with the format command (I'm a total n00b).  I played around with it and got the unhexlify stuff working that Martijin suggested and now things are working!  Hooray!

Comment: Print out the result; you are producing *literal strings*, not *single bytes*. Each element now is 4 characters, not 1. The representation of one is `\\x00`; note the double backslash; that is Python escaping the backslash because a single backslash followed by an `x` and two hex digits is an escape code to be able to specify non-printable bytes, just like `\n` encodes a newline character.